# Exchange rate volatility

Tags: applied-econometrics

Colleagues,
I have started an analysis on spatial econometrics models, and looking for data to compute an exchange rate volatility. My variables to construct the weight matrices are all bilateral including FDI, Trade and et.c
My samples are 15 african countries, and is a bit cumbersome to get their bilateral exchange rates. The only possible way is to get rates per one unit of dollar.
* Where can I get a compiled data about it? and/or How could I compute the bilateral counterpart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes more sense to use the USD as an intermediary currency.  If you know the central South African and Nigerian exchanges rates are for example

- $14.38\; ZAR = 1\; USD$
- $364 \, NGN = 1\, USD$

then by division $\frac{14.38}{364}$ or $\frac{364}{14.38}$

- $0.0395\,  ZAR \approx 1 \, NGN$
- $25.3 \, NGN \approx 1 \, ZAR$